# parallel algorithm for generalized nonsymmetric eigenproblems

Tags: python, matlab, parallel-processing, intel-mkl, eigenvalue

I need to efficiently solve large nonsymmetric generalized eigenvalue/eigenvector problems.

A x = lambda B x

A, B - general real matrices

A - dense

B - mostly sparse

x - the eigenvector

lambda - the eigenvalue

Could someone help me by:

1. Informing me if the nonsymmetric generalized eigenvalue/eigenvector problems is known to be parallelized. (What are some good algorithms and libraries implementing them if any);
2. Telling me if scalapack is an alternative to dense nonsymmetric eigenproblems;
3. Suggesting some good computational alternatives to test the use of both sparse matrices and linear-algebra algorithms;
4. Suggesting an alternative linear algebra construction that I could use (if there are no simple routines call, perhaps there is a good solution that is not so simple).

I tested code efficiency using matlab, python and C programming. Matlab is said to have builtin lapack functionality. I used intel provided python, with scipy and numpy linking to intel MKL lapack and blas libraries. I also used C code linking to intel MKL lapack and blas libraries.

I was able to check that for non-generalized eigenvalue problems, the code ran in parallel. I had as many threads as physical cores in my machine. That told me that LAPACK uses parallel code in certain routines. (Either LAPACK itself or the optimized versions shipped within matlab and intel MKL oneapi libraries.

When I started to run generalized eigenvalue routines, I observed that the code ran with only one thread. I tested in matlab and python as distributed by intel.

I'd like to investigate this further, but first I need to know if it's possible even in theory to run generalized nonsymmetric eigen decompositions in parallel.

I've seen that scipy have routines for the reduction of a pair of general matrices to a pair of hessenberg/upper triagular matrices. It seems that from hessenberg form, that eigenvalue/eigenvector problems are computationally easier.

Hessenberg for a single matrix runs in parallel. But hessenberg for a pair of matrices, runs only in sequence with one thread. (tested in python scipy). And again, I hit a wall. Which raises the question: is this problem parallelizable?

Other source of optimization for the problem I have is that I have one of the matrices dense and the other is mostly sparse. I'm still not sure how to exploit this. Are there good implementations of sparse matrices and state of the art linear algebra algorithms that work well together?

Thank you very much for any help supplied! Including books and scientific papers.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For MKL-provided routines, you can run it in either parallel mode by using **/Qmkl** compiler option (**Intel compilers**) or in sequential mode using **/Qmkl:sequential** option. For more details, you can refer to the MKL developer reference manual for more details https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/onemkl-linux-developer-guide/top/linking-your-application-with-onemkl.html regarding linking options
Here is the link which shows the MKL routines that use sparse matrices  https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/onemkl-developer-reference-c/top/sparse-solver-routines.html